# How to load large data set from controller to view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to load more than 2 MB data(15000 records) using ajax in ASP.net MVC. In ajax call if data is more than 2 MB ajax response is coming as null, if less than 2 MB it is coming perfectly.

I have added following in my web.config

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644" />
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>

 <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>



<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
```

But nothing worked for me. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance,

Anoop Xaviour.

Comment: I always find adding   <system.web><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="50000000" />  </system.web> gets around these sort of problems.

Answer (score 0):

With really large data sets it is worth considering server-side processing: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html . With this method, since all the processing is done on the server by an SQL engine which is designed for exactly this sort of thing (unlike Javascript!) it is super fast and can cope with massive data sets (I've seen DataTables using 20 million+ records). The tradeoff is that you need an XHR request for each table draw, which might or might not be acceptable given your setup.

I'd also, personally, tend to avoid infinite scrolling - I don't like it as an interface paradigm for a table - personally I much prefer Scroller: http://datatables.net/extras/scroller/ . That can be used with large data sets with data being loaded by Ajax and deferred rendering enabled.

Comment: Hi Naser, Thanks for your quick reply. In our case we are doing lot of client side operations like aggregation, pivot, drawing graphs etc with these data. Our intention is to avoid server call for each operation and get the data initially and do the manipulations on client side.